# Create a clustered primary key on partitioned table

Tags: sql-server, database-design, partitioning, clustered-index, clustered-primary-key

I have a table that has been partitioned recently based on a datetime column. The same table had a primary key (clustered) on the ID column. During the partitioning of the table, the primary key is dropped. Again after the partitioning when I tried creating the primary key (clustered) again, It created without any errors. But to my surprise when  I checked the table the partition was removed. Thus on doing more research on this, I found that when we create a new clustered index on a partitioned table the partition goes off.

Can anyone please help me out in creating a clustered primary key on the partitioned table, since non clustered primary key is degrading the performance.

Comment: ALL unique constraints (that would include a primary key) involved in a partitioning scenario MUST have the partition column defined as part of the base index definition (subset of the index key) - (not merely an included column). In order to use your existing paritition setup, you'd have to include the `datetime` as part of the primary key.  Alternatively, you could create a completely different partition scheme and partition function to support the primary key, but the clustered and non-clustered indexes would not be aligned preventing you from using `switch` or `truncate`.

Comment: @ScottHodgin Since my column used for partitioning allows null value, I can't include this column while creating the primary key. Is there any other way out ?

Comment: I think your only option is to create a separate partition function and scheme for the primary key.  However, as I indicated in my first comment - the clustered and non-clustered indexes would not be aligned preventing you from using `switch` or `truncate`.